# Deploy Java to many customers' EE containers?

Tags: java, maven

I understand that I can build a project and store it within a company maven repository using Nexus. However, beyond this we have hundreds of customers whom we'd like to run something like JBoss with our app installed on their own supplied equipment. Each of these customer installations is behind a firewall - we can't get at them within lots of manual intervention.

Question is what tools can be used to check for and install updates on the customer premises periodically from our maven repo? I'm seeing lots about Maven deploy to a repo but nothing about getting that deployment downloaded and installed to customer JBoss installations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maven is ill-suited for your requirement.

You could look at placing a small script/software on each customer system running your application, which periodically polls for newer versions of the software and then downloads/updates them.

Comment: Thanks, do you happen to know an existing solution?